# How to set text in textView which is in NavigationView

Tags: java, android

I am getting null pointer exception while setting text in textview. textview is in navigation view in dashboard activity.

In main activity, i am trying to set text like this :

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        TextView StudentNameView = (TextView) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
        StudentNameView.setText("Test");
}
}
```

Here is my dashboard activity's xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_dashboard" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dashboard"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_dashboard_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my navigation header menu is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">



    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing" android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
       android:id="@+id/studentName"
        />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" android:id="@+id/studentEmail" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where you are assigning the navigationView?

Comment: TextView StudentNameView =(TextView)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
Where is **navigationView**

Comment: Can you show what you want to develop? So probably we can develop it without TextView.

Comment: In Java we use CamelCase. I suggest you to avoid naming variables with capital letter - `TextView StudentNameView` should be `TextView studentNameView`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

More important is to use lib version v7:23.1.1
use compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

In your code write following lines

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View v = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView avatarContainer = (TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace R.layout.`NAME_OF_LAYOUT` with name of layout where your TextView is

> View navView =
>   LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.NAME_OF_LAYOUT, null);

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    View navView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.NAME_OF_LAYOUT, null); //navigation header menu layout
    TextView StudentNameView = (TextView)   navView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
    StudentNameView.setText("Test");

   }
}
```

---

EDIT:

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    View navView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.NAME_OF_LAYOUT, null); //navigation header menu layout
    TextView StudentNameView = (TextView)   navView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
    StudentNameView.setText("Test");

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    navigationView.addHeaderView(navView);

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have implemented your code, there is no null pointer exception but when i run app, text view is empty.

Comment: Are you using Navigation Drawer Activity Template from Android Studio?

Comment: Yes I am using it from Android studio

Comment: I added EDIT. Try this

Answer (score 1):

```
 NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View view = navView.getHeaderView(0);
      TextView   StudentNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you Taken The reference of `NavigationView` and `View` before getting a `TextView` Reference ?? (Something like this)

```
android.support.design.widget.NavigationView navigationView= (NavigationView) findViewById (R.id.nav_view);

View view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

do what i write, maybe it will help you friend

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View v = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txt_nama = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_nama);
    txt_nama.setText("Halo, " + nama);
```